# COLDFUSION Delete and Edit Checkboxes

Tags: sql, checkbox, coldfusion, edit, sql-delete

Attempting to make a ColdFusion edit and delete section on an admin page.  The checkboxes can be selected and then either edit or delete the selected user.

Below is the code.

```
<td>
    <input type = "text" name = "firstname" value = "#firstname#">
    <input type = "text" name = "lastname" value = "#lastname#">
    <input type = "text" name = "email" value = "#email#">
    <input type = "text" name = "user_name" value = "#user_name#">
    <input type = "text" name = "password" value = "#password#">
</td>
<td width="120">

    <input type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="Edit"> Edit <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Delete" value="#ID#"> Delete <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Changes" id = "Submit">

<!-- Action Page-->
<cfif isDefined("FORM.Delete") AND #Form.Delete# NEQ "">
<cfquery datasource = "feic_test">
    DELETE FROM UserLogin
    WHERE username = <cfqueryparam value = "#FORM.username#"
                            cfsqltype = "cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
</cfif>
```

The code is not finished but what I have so far.  How can I get it to have two checkboxes, one for edit and one for delete, and then once the submit button is clicked, the action is taken of wither editing the username on the database or deleting it?

Comment: I don't like the way this code starts, but I'm sure you have your reasons.... Where is the username stored so far? Like, in the URL? Is there a form field? Session?

Comment: This is my first attempt so I apologize if it's super sloppy.  username is stored on a db = feic_test.  table name is UserLogin,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I get it to have two checkboxes, one for edit and one for delete, and then once the submit button is clicked, the action is taken of wither editing the username on the database or deleting it.

Comment: Use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="action" value="Edit"> Edit <br>
<input type="radio" name="action" value="Delete"> Delete <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Changes" id = "Submit">

<!-- Action Page-->
<cfif isDefined("FORM.action") AND #Form.action# eq "Delete">
<cfquery datasource = "feic_test">
    DELETE FROM UserLogin
    WHERE username = <cfqueryparam value = "#FORM.username#"
                            cfsqltype = "cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
<cfelseif isDefined("FORM.action") AND #Form.action# eq "Edit">
<!--- Edit code --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Same as above, change the code but it did not execute on the page.

Comment: Are you passing the username in the form as well? It's not part of the code snippet you posted.

Comment: I'm not quite certain.  What would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that #username# is the primary key

Currently when you check edit, you are not pushing over the #ID#. I am assuming that #ID is the

You probably want your form fields like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="#username#"> Edit <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Delete" value="#username#"> Delete <br>

<!-- Action Page-->
<cfquery>
   DELETE
   FROM UserLogin
   WHERE username IN (<cfqueryparam value = "#FORM.delete#"
                       cfsqltype = "cf_sql_varchar" list="yes">)
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I put the code in and went to submit the change but nothing had changed on the page.

Comment: 1) Your code did not have any edit functionality
2) All this would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why would this question be better on Code Review? It would be off-topic there, since the code does not already work as intended.